# script invoked by expect spawn is not running, when same command works via terminal

Tags: macos, bash, shell, automation, expect

I have yet another problem with this expect stuff.  I've tried eight ways to Sunday to get this to work and can't seem to figure it out.  Basically, I want to either "call a script" within the expect spawn process or figure out how to invoke sudo and then run a set of Mac CLI commands as an elevated prompt.

Here are the commands I want to run (they need to be run as admin):

```
#!/bin/bash

networksetup -setdnsservers "Ethernet" 172.xxx.xxx.xxx;
networksetup -setsearchdomains "Ethernet" "congo.test";
```

I named this file "change.sh"

Basically, I want to setup some network interfaces first before running the main install script that I have working now.

Here is what I have that doesn't seem to work, however, it works find when invoked directly on the command line:

```
expect -c "
set password \"foobar\"
spawn su root -c \"/bin/bash change.sh\"
expect \"Password:\"
send \"\$password\r\"
"
```

Now, I know I can pass in an argv, which I will most likely do for final run, but this is NOT working, it never actually seems to fire the script and run the network change.  If I run:

```
%> su root -c ./change.sh
```

This works.  However, it's not working in the expect script.

I have another script, called "install.sh" and this works fine with the following code above:

```
spawn su root -c \"/bin/bash install.sh\"
expect \"Password:\"
send \"\$password\r\"
"
```

This works perfectly.

Two questions:

1. Can I just call those networksetup cli's within the main script? and if so, why won't calling this "change.sh" script work?
2. For the "install.sh" script, the spawn successfully fires as root and works great, they seem like completely the same thing

I'm sure it's a silly issue that I'm encountering and need to fix something somewhere.

Comment: try specifying the full path to the script: `spawn su root -c {/bin/bash /path/to/change.sh}`

Comment: nope, that didn't do it..

Answer (score 2):

Oddly, this worked:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /Users/wqcoleman/Desktop/

expect -c "
set password \"william1\"
spawn su root -c \"/bin/bash /Users/wqcoleman/Desktop/change.sh\"
expect \"Password:\"
send \"\$password\r\"
interact
"
```

With the interact at the conclusion of the snippet.  Not sure why?  maybe someone can answer this for me, but clearly interact has something to do with "timing?" or maybe the execution of the steps within change.sh?  Anyway, it worked.

Comment: actually, I was WRONG.  All the interact does is add a BIT MORE time to the timeout.  If I set the timeout to something higher than the default, the script runs and we are all good.

Comment: you can also use `sleep 10` for example where 10 is the number of seconds

Comment: I realize that this comment is ~2 years late but...: expect sends a SIGHUP to underlying spawned processes before it exists.  If these scripts are supposed to out-live the expect script you may want to use  `spawn -ignore SIGHUP ...` in the span line in the expect script to avoid killing the spawned subprocess. HTH.